# T-SQL constraint to ensure table is append only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, immutability

I want to use an append-only model for a table in my SQL Server database, and am looking for a way to enforce this usage. I was hoping there would be a constraint I could add to the table that would disallow updating, but can't find anything along those lines.

I could deny update rights to the SQL user through table-level permissions, but I can't guarantee that another SQL user couldn't update that table.

```
DENY DELETE ON [dbo].[append_only] TO [public]
DENY UPDATE ON [dbo].[append_only] TO [public]
```

A trigger can do the job, but I've generally avoided those over the years because I think they're not easily discoverable.

What other options do I have?

Comment: Are you the only sysadmin on this server? There is nothing you could do to protect your table from sysadmin, and in most cases even db_owner can get around of all your "protections"

Comment: Good point, though I'm not really concerned if a user with elevated permissions runs custom SQL to change the table's contents. I mainly want this to remind me during development not to update a row in this particular table.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger could be defined to throw an error when any SQL user attempts and update or delete.

```
create table append_only (
    id int identity primary key,
    val nvarchar(50)
)

create or alter trigger append_only_monitor
on append_only
instead of update, delete
as throw 51000, 'This table is meant to be append-only.', 1;
```

Comment: There are many ways, for example not DENY UPDATE/DELETE on that table. Still priviliged user could EXECUTE `TRUNCATE TABLE append_only` and your trigger will fail to protect data.

Comment: Also your trigger is `AFTER`, for performance reason I would probably use INSTEAD OF trigger.